Path of the Giant Elemental Cleaver - throwing weapon interaction with other rules
Elemental Cleaver applies the thrown property to a weapon you are holding when you enter rage:

When you enter your rage, you can choose one weapon that you are
holding and infuse it with one of the following damage types: acid,
cold, fire, thunder, or lightning. While you wield the infused weapon
during your rage, the weapon's damage type changes to the chosen type,
it deals an extra 1d6 damage of the chosen type when it hits, and it
gains the thrown property, with a normal range of 20 feet and a long
range of 60 feet.

Thrown Property:

If a weapon has the thrown property, you can throw the weapon to make
a ranged attack. If the weapon is a melee weapon, you use the same
ability modifier for that attack roll and damage roll that you would
use for a melee attack with the weapon. For example, if you throw a
handaxe, you use your Strength, but if you throw a dagger, you can use
either your Strength or your Dexterity, since the dagger has the
finesse property.

First Question: If I apply this ability to a ranged weapon and throw the weapon, am I making a ranged weapon attack (as opposed to throwing a melee weapon which would be "a ranged attack with a melee weapon")?
Second Question: If I am making a ranged weapon attack, can I then use other abilities that depend on that to function? e.g. Sharpshooter, Sneak Attack, Kensei's Shot, Archery Fighting Style

You are making a ranged attack [with a weapon]
As the Sage Advice Compendium explains, a "ranged weapon attack" is a ranged attack, with a weapon.  If the rules meant an attack with a ranged weapon, they would say a ranged-weapon attack.
If you have a ranged weapon, and use it as designed, you are making a ranged attack [with a weapon].  If you use elemental cleaver to give it the thrown property and then throw it, you are still making a ranged attack [with a weapon].  Elemental cleaver hasn't changed anything.
Incidentally, if you 'threw a melee weapon' with the thrown property it would be ranged attack [with a melee weapon].  If you threw a melee weapon without the thrown property, it would not be a ranged attack [with a melee weapon]; rather, it would be a ranged attack [with an improvised weapon].
Other features trigger, but might not like to be used "thrown"
Archery fighting style says:

You gain a +2 bonus to attack rolls you make with ranged weapons.

Note that the requirement is a ranged weapon, not a ranged attack.  You had a ranged weapon before you used elemental cleaver and you have a ranged weapon after you used elemental cleaver and threw the weapon.  Nothing has changed, so you may still use Archery fighting style.  Note that this works even though you can't normally use Archery fighting style with thrown weapons, because normally thrown weapons are not ranged weapons.  In your case, you have added the thrown property to a weapon and then thrown it, but you have not removed the ranged property, so the fighting style is still valid.  Also note that you can use the Archery fighting style even with things that are not bows, such as Darts1.  As long as they are ranged weapons, as per the feature description, they work.
Sneak attack says:

Beginning at 1st level, you know how to strike subtly and exploit a foe’s distraction. Once per turn, you can deal an extra 1d6 damage to one creature you hit with an attack if you have advantage on the attack roll. The attack must use a finesse or a ranged weapon.

Ignoring finesse, in order to use Sneak Attack, you must be using a ranged weapon.  Note that the requirement is a ranged weapon, not a ranged attack.  You had a ranged weapon before you used elemental cleaver and you have a ranged weapon after you used elemental cleaver and threw the weapon.  Nothing has changed, so you may still use Sneak Attack providing you meet its other requirements.
Sharpshooter says:

You have mastered ranged weapons and can make shots that others find impossible. You gain the following benefits:
Attacking at long range doesn't impose disadvantage on your ranged weapon attack rolls.
Your ranged weapon attacks ignore half and three-quarters cover.
Before you make an attack with a ranged weapon that you are proficient with, you can choose to take a -5 penalty to the attack roll. If that attack hits, you add +10 to the attack's damage.

Sharpshooter is more complicated.  "You have mastered ranged weapons" means it applies to ranged weapons, only.  Your weapon was a ranged weapon before elemental cleaver and still is after, so you are good there.  No disadvantage for long range is applied to "ranged weapon attack rolls" (that is, attack rolls made for ranged attacks, with a weapon), for which you also qualify.  Ignoring cover is for "ranged weapon attacks", which you are making.  The damage bonus is for use with a "ranged weapon", which you have.
Thus, whether you use elemental cleaver or not, you qualify to apply all the specific bonuses of Sharpshooter.  However, your DM may take exception to the "can make shots" part.  If you are taking a weapon you normally shoot, like a crossbow, and turning it into something you can throw, like a thunderbolt, and then actually throwing it, your DM may decide that the 'natural English' sense of "shot" / shooter means your attack no longer qualifies for the feat, per its description.  Remember, the entire description of a feature is rules text - but some of it is more "rulesy" and some is more "interpretive".  Saying that you can use the Sharpshooter feat to "make shots" requires DM interpretation.
Kensei's Shot says:

You can use a bonus action on your turn to make your ranged attacks with a kensei weapon more deadly.

You are making ranged attacks, but do you have a kensei weapon?  The rules define a kensei weapon as something you can choose:

Choose two types of weapons to be your kensei weapons: one melee weapon and one ranged weapon. Each of these weapons can be any simple or martial weapon that lacks the heavy and special properties. The longbow is also a valid choice.

Provided your initial ranged weapon is also a kensei weapon, adding elemental cleaver to it should not change this qualification.  Similar to sharpshooter, though, there is a bit of narrative consideration for the DM in terms of what can be a kensei weapon.

Monks of the Way of the Kensei train relentlessly with their weapons, to the point that the weapon becomes like an extension of the body. Founded on a mastery of sword fighting, the tradition has expanded to include many different weapons.
A kensei sees a weapon much in the same way a calligrapher or a painter regards a pen or brush. Whatever the weapon, the kensei views it as a tool used to express the beauty and precision of the martial arts. That such mastery makes a kensei a peerless warrior is but a side effect of intense devotion, practice, and study.

Given this explanation, a DM might decide that throwing a lava longbow at a foe, even if the longbow temporarily has the thrown property, does not qualify as the kind of attack a kensei has trained relentlessly for, and does not express the beauty and precision of the martial arts.  Thus, it might not qualify as a kensei weapon when used this way.

1 "Archery" is not defined by the game and in a natural English sense means just bows and arrows.  However, the titles of game features are not considered to be rules text in the same way that descriptions are.

The rules covering melee or ranged attacks and melee or ranged weapons fail to achieve the "simplicity" goal of 5e, noted here.
The Path of the Giant throws a spanner in the works of an already overly complicated mechanic.

First Question: If I apply this ability to a ranged weapon and throw the weapon, am I making a ranged weapon attack (as opposed to throwing a melee weapon which would be "a ranged attack with a melee weapon")?

No.
If you make a ranged attack with a ranged weapon using the thrown property, you are effectively making a ranged attack with an improvised melee weapon. I'm not sure I see the value here, but yes, you could ostensibly throw a crossbow at an opponent. You aren't making a ranged weapon attack, where you would hit the opponent with a bolt, instead, you are making a ranged attack with a melee weapon, throwing the crossbow itself, which in this case could only make sense if it was treated as an improvised weapon.

Second Question: If I am making a ranged weapon attack, can I then use other abilities that depend on that to function? e.g. Sharpshooter, Sneak Attack, Kensei's Shot, Archery Fighting Style

It depends.
Features that only apply to ranged weapons would not apply to a thrown ranged weapon (since throwing an improvised weapon is a ranged attack, but not with a ranged weapon). Features that apply to ranged attacks would function as normal.
Arguably, rules as written may be interpreted differently.
Update
Perhaps I'm making assumptions that aren't commonly shared with how this is interpreted. All we have to go on is

When you enter your rage, you can choose one weapon that you are holding [...], it gains the thrown property, with a normal range of 20 feet and a long range of 60 feet [...]

That's it. Without this feature, if I choose to throw my sword or longbow, that's already supported by the following:

An improvised weapon includes any object you can wield in one or two hands [...] At the DM's option, a character proficient with a weapon can use a similar object as if it were that weapon and use his or her proficiency bonus.[...] An object that bears no resemblance to a weapon deals 1d4 damage [...]. An improvised thrown weapon has a normal range of 20 feet and a long range of 60 feet.

How does this feature change that? It grants whatever weapon I'm holding  the thrown property. But, wait, I can already throw it, as an improvised weapon...
So, what's the difference? I don't know for certain, as the rules don't tell you.
How would I rule?
Good question. For sure, this has to add something meaningful for the player, or it's a non-feature. It does add the Artificer's returning weapon feature, so that's nice. But what does adding the thrown property mean? I assume that means you are proficient, as otherwise, this adds nothing, avoiding disadvantage for attacking with an improvised weapon, but it isn't spelled out explicitly in the feature. I would probably default to 1d4 damage, if it didn't have the thrown property in the first place.

Improvised weapons can be thrown.  That does not mean they have the thrown property.

@Kirt - I removed references to the "property" being associated with an improvised weapon.
